# How to find all string with regular expression?

Tags: jenkins

I have s `string` like:

```
<?XML version="1.0" Encoding="UTF-8"?>\N<slave>\n <temporaryOfflineCause class="hudson.slaves.OfflineCause$SimpleOfflineCause">\n    <description>\n      <holder>\n        <owner>com.polopoly.jenkins.plugin.offlineonfailure.Messages</owner>\n      </holder>\n      <key>OfflineOnFailureCause.Description</key>\n      <args/>\n    </description>\n  </temporaryOfflineCause>\n
```

I want find all `string`s that are in between:

```
<temporaryOfflineCause class="hudson.slaves.OfflineCause$SimpleOfflineCause"></temporaryOfflineCause>
```

How do I write the regular expression statement?

Answer (score 0):

The following regular expression will give you everything in between the xml element.

```
<temporaryOfflineCause.*>(.*)<\/temporaryOfflineCause>
```

The brackets create a group.  Thus, you can retrieve the text in between it.